# My PHP code returns true even when I run exit() on the error

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo, form-submit, exit

Hi I am new here and my question may look annoying but am just sorry

In my achievements I want to prevent multiples submit button so my client's transaction will not be run multiple time using php only.

I succeed in catching client's submit button with the use of code

```
if(empty($_POST['key']) OR $_POST['key'] != $_SESSION['key'])
```

But it returns `true`  always

```
    elseif(empty($_POST['key']) OR $_POST['key'] != $_SESSION['key'])
    {
    $form= 'multiples transaction accur either you double click the options or transaction is already in progress please try again ';
    exit();
    }
//This line also return true when $mey is greater than 1
    elseif($mey > 1)
    {
    exit();
    }
```

So I added `exit();` to each line of code but it exit in browser and also return as `true` as my client Wallet balance is also deducted.
What am I doing wrong this my code below? 
Big thanks for your time and impact in my solution
This my code:

```
    <?php
    require('init.php');
    error_reporting(0);
    echo $_GET['type'];
    if(!isset($_SESSION['count']))
    {
        $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
    }
    $vote = isset($_POST['button']) ? $_POST['button'] : false;
    if($vote)
    {
        $mey = $_SESSION['count']++;
    }
    if($mey>1)
    {
        echo noo;
        unset($_SESSION['count']);
    }
    $username = $_SESSION['user_name'];
    $result = $conn->prepare('select * from users where username=:username');
    $result->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $result->execute();
    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH))
    {
        $uid = $row['id'];
        $username = $row['username'];
        $ip = $row['ip'];
        $ban = $row['validated'];
        $balance = $row['balance'];
        $pin = $row['pin'];
    }
    if(!empty($_GET['net']) && isset($_GET['number']) && $_GET['type']=='airtime' OR isset($_POST['net']) && isset($_POST['number']) && $_POST['type']=='airtime')
    {
        $nnet = $_GET['net'];
        $nnumber = $_GET['number'];
        $net = $_POST['net'];
        $number = $_POST['number'];
        $wnt = $_POST['amount'];
        if($_GET['net'] ==glo)
        {
            $dis = '3%';
        }
        else
        {
            $dis = '1.4%';
        }
        $urll = "https://m...content-available-to-author-only...g.com/httpapi/?userid=08181808888&pass=d511b7db1f2b8fc67a&network=2&phone=$numberb&amt=$wnt";
        $meg = "You are about to carry out <font
        color='red'>$nnet</font> VTU airtime transaction on <font
        color='red'>$nnumber</font>  $dis discount apply";
        $frm = '<input type="number" name="amount" placeholder="Amount"/>';
    }
    elseif(!empty($_GET['net']) && isset($_GET['number']) && $_GET['type']=='data' OR isset($_POST['net']) && isset($_POST['number']) &&
    $_POST['type']=='data')
    {
        $nnet = $_GET['net'];
        $nnumber = $_GET['number'];
        $net = $_POST['net'];
        $number = $_POST['number'];
        $wnt = $_POST['amount'];
        if($_GET['net']=='mtn' || $_POST['net']=='mtn')
        {
            $dis='1.4%';
            $tag ='<option value="">DATA PLAN</option>
            <option value="100">50MB 1day N100</option>
            <option value="500">750MB 14days N500</option>
            <option value="1000">1GB 30days 1000</option>
            <option value="1200">1.5GB 30days 1200</option>
            <option value="2000">2.5GB 30days 2000</option>
            <option value="1200">1.5GB 30days 1200</option>
            submit
            <option value="2000">2.5GB 30days 2000</option>
            <option value="1200">1.5GB 30days 1200</option>
            <option value="2000">2.5GB 30days 2000</option>
            1.5GB 30days 1200
            <option value="3500">5GB 30days 3500</option>
            <option value="3500">5GB 30days 3500</option>
            <option value="3500">5GB 30days 3500</option>
            <option value="5000">10GB 30days 5000</option>
            <option value="10000">22GB 30days 10000</option>
            </select>';
        }
        if($_GET['net']=='airtel' || $_POST['net']=='airtel')
        {
            $dis = '1.4%';
    $tag ='<option value="">DATA PLAN</option>
    <option value="100">50MB 1day N100</option>
    <option value="200">100MB 3days N200</option>
    <option value="500">750MB 14days N500</option>
    <option value="1000">1.5GB 30days 1000</option>
    <option value="1500">2.5GB 30days 1500</option>
    <option value="2000">3.5GB 30days 2000</option>
    <option value="2500">5.5GB 30days 2500</option>
    <option value="4000">9.5GB 30days 4000</option>
    <option value="5000">12GB 30days 5000</option>
    </select>';
    }
    if($_GET['net']=='mobile' || $_POST['net']=='mobile')
    {
    $dis='1.4%';
    $tag ='<option value="">DATA PLAN</option>
    <option value="200">150MB 7day N200</option>
    <option value="1000">1GB 3days N1000</option>
    <option value="1200">1.5GB 3days N1200</option>
    <option value="2000">2.5GB 3days N2000</option>
    <option value="2500">3.5GB 3days N2500</option>
    </select>';
    }
    if($_GET['net']=='glo' || $_POST['net']=='glo')
    {
    $dis='10%';
    $tag = '<option value="">DATA PLAN</option>
    <option value="100">100MB 24hrs N100</option>
    <option value="200">262MB 7days N200</option>
    <option value="500">1GB 14days N500</option>
    <option value="1000">2GB 30days N1000</option>
    <option value="2000">4.5GB 30days N2000</option>
    <option value="2500">7.2GB 30days N2500</option>
    <option value="3000">8.75GB 30days N3000</option>
    <option value="4000">12.5GB 30days N4000</option>
    <option value="5000">15.6GB 30days N5000</option>
    <option value="8000">25GB 30days N8000</option>
    <option value="10000">32.5GB 30days N10000</option>
    </select>';
    }
    $urll = "https://m...content-available-to-author-only...g.com/httpapi/datatopup.php?userid=08181808888&pass=d511b7db11f2b8fc67a&network=2&phone=$number&amt=$wnt";
    $meg="You are about to carry out <font
    color='red'>$nnet</font> VTU DATA transaction on <font
    color='red'>$nnumber</font> $dis discount apply";
    $frm ="<b>SELECT BUNDLE</b><br/><select name='amount'/>$tag<br/><br/>";
    }
    if(!empty($_POST['amount']))
    {
    $wnt = $_POST['amount'];
    $typ = $_GET['type'];
    $ch =  curl_init('https://API-url');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
    $data=curl_exec($ch);
    if(($wnt>$data)||($data==$wnt) && $balance>$wnt)
    {
    $form="<font
    color='red'>$wnt VTU is not available at this time please try again in few minuit</font></div>";
    exit();
    }
//This line of code below returns true always 
    elseif(empty($_POST['key']) OR $_POST['key'] != $_SESSION['key'])
    {
    $form= 'multiples transaction accur either you double click the options or transaction is already in progress please try again ';
    exit();
    }
    elseif($wnt > $balance)
    {
    $form= 'Insufficient balance to complete transactions Please fund your account And Try again';
    exit();
    }
//This line also return true when $mey is greater than 1
    elseif($mey > 1)
    {
    exit();
    }
    else
    {
    $ch =  curl_init("$urll");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
    $data=curl_exec($ch);
    $arr = explode("|", $data);
    $baa = $arr[0];
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $errors;
    $dutt =$wnt-$dis;
    $dedut =$balance-$dutt;
    $pad = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET balance=:redut WHERE id=:uid");
    $pad->bindParam(":redut", $dedut);
    $pad->bindParam(":uid", $uid);
    $pad->execute()
    or die(print_r($pad->errorInfo(), true));
    $tme ="insert into books (book, item_name, quantity, msg, used, seen, take) values (:book, :item_name, :quantity, :msg, :used, :seen, :take)";
    $me = $conn->prepare($tme);
    $me->bindParam(':book', $book);
    $me->bindParam(':item_name', $typ);
    $me->bindParam(':quantity', $qty);
    $me->bindParam(':msg', $number);
    $me->bindParam(':used', $load);
    $me->bindParam(':seen', $seen);
    $me->bindParam(':take', $take);
    $book=RAND(1000000, 2000000);
    $typ = $_POST["type"];
    $qty="1";
    $number = $_POST["number"];
    $load="load";
    $seen = rand_string(7);
    $take="checking";
    $me->execute()
    or die(print_r($me->errorInfo(), true));
    $_SESSION['msg']="your $net $wnt $typ transfer to $number was successfully";
    $form="your $net $wnt $typ transfer to $number was successfully";
    }
    }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://w...content-available-to-author-only...3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://w...content-available-to-author-only...3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <style type="text/css">
    {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    }
    </style>
    <title>VTU TRANSACTIONS PAGE</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <div style="width:100%; border: solid 2px #663333; " align="left">
    <div style="background-color:#663333; color:#FFFFFF; padding:3px;"><img src="../image/newmsg.png" alt="new" border="0" /><b>VTU <? echo $_GET["type"]; ?> TRANSACTION</b></div><div class='info_post'><? echo $meg; ?></div><div style="margin:30px">
    <?php
    $_SESSION['key'] = mt_rand(1, 1000);
    ?><? echo $form; ?>
    <!-- Form -->
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>#center" method="post"><? echo $frm; ?><input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['key'] ?>" /><input type="text" name="net" value="<?php echo $_GET['net'] ?>" /><input type="hidden" name="number" value="<?php echo $_GET['number'] ?>" /><input type="hidden" name="type" value="<?php echo $_GET['type'] ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="TRANSFER NOW" />
    </form></div></div>
    <div class="b_head" align="left"><img src="/image/man_key.png" width="14" height="14" style="border-radius:5px" /> WE HELP:- </div><div class="awa" align="left"><img src="image/fb.png" width="35" height="35" style="border-radius:5px" /> <font color="grey"><a href="https://f...content-available-to-author-only...k.com/solink.ml"><b> 08181808888
    </b></a></font><br/><img src="image/phone.png" width="35" height="35" style="border-radius:5px" /> <font color="grey"><a href="tel:07010710811"><b> CUSTOMER CARE
    </b></a></font></div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    require("foot.php");
    ?>
```

Comment: Which line of code has the problem? Also you have quite a few `echo` in your code those could also return true. But i don't think i understand your question that clear. Can you put the part of the code that actually has the problem and try to elaborate a bit more on the issue?

Comment: please format your code properly. I've started adding indentation for you, and to make it readable for others, you should indent the whole thing (don't forget to format html too)

Comment: please also describe what are you trying to achieve, what the code is supposed to do first, so that we can follow your description of the problem

Comment: This line of code below returns true always 
        elseif(empty($_POST['key']) OR $_POST['key'] != $_SESSION['key'])
        {
        $form= 'multiples transaction accur either you double click the options or transaction is already in progress please try again ';
        exit();
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have called session_start() in your init.php

```
$_POST['key'] != $_SESSION['key'])
```

is always true, because `$_SESSION['key']` is null.

also change this: `error_reporting(0)` to this: `error_reporting(1)` and give yourself some errors to work with (until you have eliminated them all)